# Worship of Lord Skanda in Varanasi

Tags: shiva, temple, agamas, kartikeya, kashi

So there is a common story, in short, the one about Divodasa, in which the king  removes Lord Shiva from his own city. All the devatas come one by one but end up staying in the city themselves. As such, it is said that Kashi is home to all the devatas and as per local word of mouth, one will find at least one temple of each devata.

However, there is one peculiarity in the case of Lord Skanda, Lord Shiva’s own son. Except for being the patron devata of one the akhadas and supposedly having a small temple on Niranjani Ghat, I could not find any other temple dedicated to him, as opposed to an important one for his brother - Dhundhiraja Vinayaka temple.

**Questions:**

1. Has there been historically (from Puranas) any individual temple dedicated to him (preferably tirtha places not those established later by kings), if so what is it’s condition now?
2. Since usually in all Lord shiva temples, the two sons are automatically worshipped as per agamas, was there or should there be a lord Kartikeya temple in in the compound area of or within the Shri Kashi Vishwanatha temple itself?

The question of having a Murugan temple is very important now since the original Kashi Vishwanatha would be being made again. Hopefully the answer is yes, his temple should too be consecrated in vishwanatha compound at least, along with Vinayaka.